# How to access php array inside POST method of AJAX to pass the array to another file?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

i have a php file which have a array like the following.

```
 $selectShiftarray = array();
$shift=$_POST['selectShift'];

if ($shift)
{
    foreach ($shift as $value)
    {
        array_push($selectShiftarray,$value);
    }
}
```

i need to access the $selectShiftarray inside the AJAX to pass the value to another php file.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../c/sampleTest.php', //data: {data = <?php $POST['selectShift'] ?> },//"id=78&name=Allen",
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function (json) {
        //alert('successful');
        $.plot($("#placeholder"), json, {
            series: {
                stackpercent: true,
                bars: {
                    show: true,
                    barWidth: 0.6,
                    align: "center"
                }
            },
            xaxis: {
                tickSize: 1
            },
            yaxis: {
                max: 100,
                tickFormatter: function (v, axis) {
                    return v.toFixed(axis.tickDecimals) + '%'
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

i tried to pass the array values in the data feild of the AJAX to sampleTest.php to perform calculation.

If i pass the array value directly between the two php files, i want to include the sampleTest.php inside the current php file. My requirement is, i should not include the sampleTest.php file inside any php file, hence i go for POST method of AJAX. But i can't able to pass array to the sampleTest.php file. Since i'm new to AJAX i can't solve this problem. can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: WTH would you use clientside ajax to communicate between two PHP files? Even if you don't want to use a `include` statement (for what odd reason ever), there are other ways using plain PHP.

Comment: How can i pass the array to another php file without including that php file. Can u please help me out?

Comment: Why don't you want to include? Knowing the reason would help us finding the best solution.

Comment: For plotting the grap i need only JSON. but the current php file which is a controller file, which already have included view.php file. so when the controller file is loaded, its not only have JSON file, but also the view file which has many echo statements. hence my graph is not getting plotted.

Comment: That sounds like you need a code restructuring. Put the JSON thing in its own file, and include that both in the view file and the current controller file. Apart from that, http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2010/three-ways-to-make-a-post-request-from-php

Comment: Sorry Bergi, i will explain my problem briefly. my sampleTest.php will generate and JSON for ploting the graph. i need to access the JSON inside my controller file. but to perform calculation in sampleTest.phh file i need to pass the Shift array to the sampleTest.php file without including the sampleTest.php file. Hence i'm trying to pass the array value through the POST method of AJAX. All i need is how can i access the php array inside AJAX to pass it in POST method.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20554/discussion-between-allen-and-bergi)

Answer (score 0):

Printing $selectShiftarray array into AJAX code to send it to ../c/sampleTest.php through AJAX:

```
function sendArrayToPHP(phpFile, parameterName, jsArray) {
    $.ajax({
        url: phpFile,
        async: false, // Depending on what you want
        type: "POST",
        data: { parameterName : JSON.serialize(jsArray) }
    }).done(function( data ) {
        // Sent!
    });
}

var arrayExample = $.parseJSON("<?=$selectShiftarray?>"); // This way
// You can modify here the array if you want using JavaScript
sendArrayToPHP("../c/sampleTest.php", "arrayParameter", arrayExample);
```

Receiving the array from ../c/sampleTest.php (decoding JSON):

```
$selectShiftArray = json_decode($_POST['arrayParameter'], true);
```

Comment: I'm performing calculation in sampleTest.php and echoing a JSON. i'm accessing it in the AJAX. But my question is to pass the array from the AJAX in the POST method.

Comment: is jsArray is a php array, i.e as per my question `$selectShiftarray`.

Comment: i will explain my problem briefly. my sampleTest.php will generate and JSON for ploting the graph. i need to access the JSON inside my controller file. but to perform calculation in sampleTest.phh file i need to pass the Shift array to the sampleTest.php file without including the sampleTest.php file. Hence i'm trying to pass the array value through the POST method of AJAX. All i need is how can i access the php array inside AJAX to pass it in POST method.

Comment: So do you want to have the same array you have in PHP but in your JavaScript code?

Comment: The two snippet of code i have given above in my question is from single file, controller.php. i need to pass the shiftArray from the php to another file sampleTest.php through AJAX POST.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20555/discussion-between-axelbrz-and-allen)

Comment: the problem is, the entered text in the chat is not going to u.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to axelbrz and Bergi for their Guidance which helped me to solve this problem , This Works for me,

Here is my AJAX code in Controller :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

    var jsonobj = <?php echo json_encode($selectShiftarray); ?>;


    $.ajax({type:'POST',url:'../c/sampleTest.php', data :  { shift : jsonobj } ,
    dataType: 'json',

    success:function(json){
    //alert('successful');
    $.plot($("#placeholder"), json, {
    series: {
        stackpercent: true,
        bars: { show: true, barWidth: 0.6, align: "center" }
    },
        xaxis: {tickSize : 1},
        yaxis:{max:100, tickFormatter: function(v,axis){ return v.toFixed(axis.tickDecimals)+'%'}}
    });
 }
 });
 });

</script>
<div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px; top: -401px; left: 500px;">
</div>
```

My sampleTest.php code, which receives the array send by controller and processing it.

```
$selectShiftarray = array();
$shift=$_POST['shift'];

if ($shift)
{
    foreach ($shift as $value)
    {
        array_push($selectShiftarray,$value);
    }
}
```